# How to cancel animation of backview

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to cancel animation of back preview. How can I do that?

```
.controller('DemoController', function($scope, $ionicHistory) {
    $scope.goBack() = function(){
          $ionicHistory.viewHistory().backView.go();
    }

})
```

Comment: did you try this  $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions()` for this purpose.
This method can be useful to override certain view/transition defaults right before a view transition happens.

Available options:

`disableAnimate`: Do not animate the next transition.

`disableBack`: The next view should forget its back view, and set it to null.

`historyRoot`: The next view should become the root view in its history stack.

Set property `disableAnimate` to `true` for disable the animation

**Controller**

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
      disableAnimate: true
});
```

**[Refer](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)**

Comment: @woshikange Glad to help you